# Is it possible to make GoogleTest for a QMLExtensionPlugin?

Tags: qt, qml, googletest

I'm trying GoogleTest for the first time and I need to test a QML plugin. I am working in QtCreator and I have already made a QuickTest for the same plugin. But I also wanted to run GoogleTest on the same. I went through the README for GoogleTest and I believe I have configured the project correctly, but I'm now getting 'undefined reference errors', probably due to incorrectly linking my library.

But then I began to wonder if it is actually possible to make a GoogleTest for a QML Extension Plugin. Or if it is possible is really a good idea to use GoogleTest over QuickTest? I could not find any examples of GoogleTest on QML Plugins.  Can anyone throw some light on usage of GoogleTest on QML plugins please?